# Unable to query Azure Search using jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I set the CORS to "All" for the Azure Search Index I'm trying to query, and also added "*" to the blob storage that the index is hitting. I've tried a variety of query params / options, but still run into the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error. I'm running from Eclipse, a tomcat server, java web app, which calls the javascript function. I'm passing the api-key for the Search service and setting the headers; where is this going wrong? I also tried deploying the web app to a VM in Azure in the same datacenter and same resource group, and still get the same error. I've tried adding the beforeSend function as well to the ajax call, didnt help.

```
var index = "https://<my-azure-storage>-azuresearch.search.windows.net/indexes/<my-search-index>/docs?";
var params = encodeURIComponent("api-version=2016-09-01&search=hematology");
var theUrl = index + params;
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: theUrl,
    headers: {'api-key': "<azure-search-main-admin-key>",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Search Result" + data);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, e) {
        alert("Error (jqxhr): " + jqxhr.responseText);
        alert("Error Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error (e): " + e);
    }
});
```

Error in browser:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://..url../docs?api-version%3D2016-09-01%26search%3Dhematology. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: When you say `I set the CORS to "All" for the Azure Search Index`, you meant the setting in portal which sets `*` as allowed origins. Correct? Also, you should not use your admin key for this (security reasons). Use one of the query keys.

Comment: Yes through the portal, sets them all to *. I'll set a query key as well; seems there is a default one with a name: <empty>, is it ok to use that? or should I make one?

Comment: You would need to create a new query key. If I am not mistaken you can create up to 50 query keys per search service.

Comment: created a new key, still same issue.

Comment: FYI, the <empty> query key works just fine. No need to create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you could try this way:

1. As Bruce Johnston Said,  change the verb to `GET`.
2. Use function `encodeURI` instead of `encodeURIComponent` to encode the query string.

And the code look like:

```js
var index = "https://<my-azure-storage>-azuresearch.search.windows.net/indexes/<my-search-index>/docs?";
var params = encodeURI("api-version=2016-09-01&search=hematology");
var theUrl = index + params;
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: theUrl,
  headers: {'api-key': "<azure-search-main-admin-key>", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
    alert("Search Result" + data);
  },
  error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, e) {
    alert("Error (jqxhr): " + jqxhr.responseText);
    alert("Error Status: " + textStatus);
    alert("Error (e): " + e);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @K Jackson, is this helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks. Got too caught up in the preflight error that I didnt really consider the 400 error. I thought I had tried using "GET" before as well and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a CORS issue (as indicated by the 400 error). It looks like you're mixing up the format of the GET and POST versions of the [Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/Search-Documents). Specifically, you have the `search` parameter on the query string and apparently no request body. If you want to send your search parameters on the query string, change the verb to GET.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put your api key in the url

```
 var url = 'https://NAME.search.windows.net/indexes/INDEX-NAME/docs?api-version=2015-02-28&highlight=description&fuzzy=true&api-key=YOURAPIKEY&search='+searchString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the url for the POST request is slightly different, it includes an additional route part "/search" at the end of the url.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents

Comment: Your comment does not answer the question. You will be able to add comments to questions when you have enough reputation points. Your text would be a good comment but it may not be acceptable as an answer.